# PHP how to return variable without echo

Tags: php, function, variables, return

Im looking to return one or another string variable from my php function. 
I dont want to echo the string in the function i just want to return the variable, and then output it later in the code.
The following code represents my code (simplified):

```
<?php
$a = NULL;
$b = NULL;
myFunction($this);
function myFunction($this) {
   if($this === a) {
       return $a = "its a";
   }else{
       return $another = "its something else";
   }
}
?>
<html>
   MARKUP
   <?php echo $a; ?>
   <?php echo $b; ?>
```

Comment: You dont ever call the function in your example, what are you actually trying to do???

Comment: The example code makes no sense. I would *guess* that you're trying to implicitly set the value of the global `$a` and `$b` variables from within the function. But that's a terrible practice and not something you should ever do in production code.

Comment: sorry - im calling the function now. i just want to echo the returned variable string later in my html markup.

Comment: is it bad practice like that? so if i have many functions, the global variable will be changed according to the returned string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how to work functions.

```
function myFunction($this, $a) {
   if($this === $a) {
       return "its a";
   }else{
       return "its something else";
   }
}
$result = myFunction($this, $a);
```

I think you want to do this

Answer (score 2):

```
$store_var_value = myFunction($this);
```

You can save returned value in a variable to use it later.

Comment: That makes sense, but what i forgot to mention is that the container for either $a or $b is styled differently, so they cant be outputted the same place

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to all the other answers I think your problem might be that you never define `$this`and also how are you planning to echo the value of `myFunction(...)` later if you never store it anywhere?
If I understand what you are trying to do correctly this code should work:

```
<?php
$a = NULL;
$b = NULL;
$another = NULL;
$aaa = myFunction($this);
function myFunction($that)
{
  $result = -1;
  if($that === $a)
  {
    $a = "it's the good 'n old a";
    $result = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    $another = "Hey it's someone else";
    $result = 1;
  }
  return result;
}
?>
<div id="div a">
<?php
if($aaa == 0)
{
  echo $a;
}
?> 
</div>
<div id="div b">
<?php
if($aaa == 1)
{
  echo $another;
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: well my problem is that i didnt store the returned string. i want to echo the string of $a in one div and $b in another div.